# What's the proper way to compare a known type with an unknown type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g.:

```
const arr = [0] as const;

const n = Math.random();
console.log(arr.includes(n));
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gBgLrwjUSKAbgChTDoYxUYBZOKACwDoE4wATEAWwAoAlGUogANgFMWokAHM+iBCwCWYYKICuncRD5gBQoA

It's possible for `Math.random()` to be 0, but TS throws: `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '0'.`

A realistic example is comparing user input with an union of known strings. The user input is just a generic `string`, so TS would throw errors saying I can't compare it with the known strings. I don't want to cast the user input into the known strings because it's possible that the user input isn't one of the known strings.

Is there a proper way to resolve this?

Comment: Read about narrowing: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html. If the built-in options don't work you can always write your own type predicate.

Comment: And if you want a typescript-native validator for arbitrary user input, https://github.com/colinhacks/zod has proven excellent.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255

Comment: "*It's possible for Math.random() to be 0, but TS throws: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '0'.*" it's also possible to not be zero. So...it's a correct error message. If you ask me for coffee and I give you a box that might either contain a cup of coffee or spiders with clown faces, you'd probably hesitate to open it and take a sip.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript will sometimes, perhaps helpfully, perhaps not, infer the type as narrower than you would like.

Here's a simple example:

```
let a = "hello"; 
a = 9; //Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

Here, what's happening is that TypeScript isn't reading ahead to see that you are later going to reassign `a`.

The solution is to explicitly widen the type:

```
let a = "hello" as string | number; 
a = 9;
```

In your scenario, let's compare two things:

```
const a1 = [0]; //const a1: number[]
const a2 = [0] as const; //const a2: readonly [0]
```

Note that `a2` is inferred as static array containing a single 0, while `a1` is just an array of numbers.

This is because with that `as const` declaration, you've told TypeScript 'this array is immutable' - so it's impossible for it to be anything than `[0]` (trying to use the `.push` method will give type errors).

Note that you *don't* get the error you are seeing with `a1`:

```
const n1 = Math.random();
console.log(a1.includes(n1));

const n2 = Math.random();
console.log(a2.includes(n2)); //Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '0'.(2345)
```

So to give you an answer around your 'unknown string' scenario, it's a little more complicated.

What I would suggest, is that what you want is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates).

What a type predicate does, is it's a runtime function that returns a boolean, (in this case 'check that the unknown string is in the array of known strings'), but it provides a compile time hint to TypeScript, 'if this function returns true, then I can treat it as that type'.

Here's my example:

```js
type KnownString = "foo" | "bar" |"biz"; 

const knownStrings = ["foo", "bar", "biz"] as Array<KnownString>; 

// Type predicate function
// It's really just a function that returns a boolean 
function isKnownString(str: string) : str is KnownString {
    return (knownStrings as Array<string>).includes(str);
}

// Here the unknown string will either be returned as a KnownString type, 
// or will throw an error
function parseUnknownString(str: string) : KnownString {

    if (isKnownString(str)) { // From here TypeScript knows that the type is `KnownString`
        return str; 
    }
    
    else throw new Error ("Unrecognised string"); 
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgRhgXhgbQAwF0DcMD0+oksiAXDGAK4C2ARgKYBOaWAUMdPAEwrrbwIMTlDyERPCkwZwAJuAA2AT37s2HcFzBJUAWThQAFgDomcMPJoAKAJQ4NkEAobGFIAOZXExgJZhgClSyDBBW2jZ26hJgvHoGJmYWINaRnE4ubp5w3L7+gcGhMRFi+ACCTO60DGCwIABmMFBKAA4MMADk1PTM7TA+QmAgpBAQPu5gcHTOjSAwzXBmNAxQzDD1jS1t7RjtxlbcAMwALACsNurqTa0wANKDAO5gAMpQTH7ufABEdSAgnzAAHxgnzoC3+AJBPgAXp88FFNLAANYPZ6vd5CVBob6-T4AGmBoKYeIJ0M+WEEMHKZiUAB47iBHi83mB3AA+OFsOpUfxQHzgPoQemMtEsqzQJgUcXvGwwSWvAW3FFM94wADebBgmpg0igVCYYBgVmRDNRzPcQjgQipcFpUpZrJsuQCQRCYtedhgbAAvuouTy+Qb5kwIAwAKpgY3Cs1uiUwO3uGUUIWmlXqjVanwNKz9ZPK0XiiJq9NarU6vUG8Vwks+kvFmAMBQhxqGJgMygMe4wACiTFbTENn3D0g8YH6DFkcZF7k+Hu9QA)

Comment: The issue is with `const _str = str as KnownString;`, I don't like doing this because it's not necessarily true, I'd rather use `@ts-ignore`. But I was hoping there's a better solution that doesn't involve forcing type casts or `@ts-ignore`

Comment: Alternatively, you can cast the array `knownStrings` as `readonly string[]`. And it is indeed true because ReadonlyArray<KnownString> is subtype of ReadonlyArray<string> (covariance).

Comment: `let a = "hello" as string | number;` instead of `let a: string | number = "hello";`? I don't see why not use type annotations for what they *are* and use type assertion.

Comment: "*Note that a2 is inferred as static array containing a single 0*" TypeScript calls those [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

Comment: @LeoJiang Sure, I've updated my answer as per Wang's comment. It's a bit of same diff as the type predicate is _meant_ to be a manual check that that the type matches, (ie if you screw up the function, you will get typings that don't match what they really are).